# c++ double doesn't work

Tags: c++, double

Why in c++ double doesn't work if I write:

```
int a, b;
double c;

a=11;
b=2;
c=a/b;
```

right answer according to me should be 5,5 but it writes just 5 anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: because int/int = int, so do a*1./b, or (double)a/b, or C++ way `static_cast<double>(a)/b;`

Comment: Check this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256829/c-program-why-does-this-array-have-this-output/28256899

Comment: C++ doesn't look at the type of the result when it does the calculation, it performs the calculation based on the types of the operands (which are both integer) and *then* converts the result. You fix it by making sure one of the operands *isn't* int.

Answer (score 3):

A division of an `int` by another `int` yields an `int`. This occurs before the quotient is assigned to the `double` variable.

To fix this, cast at least one of the `int` values to a `double`. In other words, change this:

```
c=a/b;
```

to this:

```
c = static_cast<double>(a) / b;
```

Comment: And if `static_cast<double>` is too wordy for you, a quick way to get a double from an int is addition: `(a+0.0)`.

Answer (score 0):

a must be double too, or float

```
double a,b,c;
```

That'll work